# Can I get adb server port number?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu, adb

I tried connecting an android tv device to an android studio with ip(no wifi) in Ubuntu. The device is connected to a LAN and is using adb command by connecting to the window with USB. I tried to connect "adb connect {ip address:5555}" to device, but it is not working well. I was trying to get the port number of the adb server because I thought the port number of the adb server was not assigned as 5555, but I couldn't find a way, so I'm asking you a question.

Additionally, Please tell me if there's a way to connect Android TV devices to Android studios with ip(no wifi) in Ubuntu!

Comment: Afaik ADB only works with Wi-Fi, not with ethernet or any other network connection. If your device does not support Wi-Fi, you cannot use wireless debugging with adb.

Comment: Ehm. ADB Doesn't care about the connection type. You can use it with an ethernet connection or a WiFi the stack is TCP/IP

Comment: Just a short note: Within adb the term "server" is not what is running on the device, that part is `adbd`. adb server is running on the PC you are developing with, it manages all the different adb connections, e.g. via USB and IP. So your question should be "Can I get the adbd port number". For adb wireless your TV may be too old and for a manual TCP connection you first need to establish an USB connection to enable the TCP port in adbd.

Comment: Did you try `nmap <IP-Address of your TV>`? nmap will list the open ports so if the adbd is listening to a different port, it will show up.

Comment: Did you enable adb debugging on your TV settings?

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. The problem is still unresolved. In fact, the key is connecting devices from Android studio in Ubuntu using ip. In Ubuntu, the ping {device ip} command works. But adb connect {device ip:5555} still times out in Ubuntu.

Anyway, I think it's taking a lot of time to set up, so I decided to use USB and use it. Thank you again for your reply.